# lvalue required as left operand of assignment (C program)

Tags: c

I am getting an error of `"lvalue required as left operand of assignment"`.

It assigns to the line:

```
if(ch=='.' || ch=='"' || ch=='(' || ch=')' || ch=='!' || ch==',' || ch=='?' || ch==';') { etc }
```

I just want to check if the character I'm looking at is equal to any one of those characters. Any idea on the fix?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10):

`ch=')'` should be `ch==')'`. The reason you are getting that particular error is because while `==` has higher precedence than `||`, `=` has lower precedence, so this:

```
ch == '(' || ch = ')'
```

is parsed as

```
((ch == '(') || ch) = ')'
```

Which is trying to assign `')'` to the result of `(ch == '(') || ch)` which is an rvalue and not assignable. This is a common mistake, and this technique is used to avoid it:

```
if ('.' == ch || '"' == ch || ...)
```

Notice that the character literals and the variable have switched places around the `==`. That way, if you accidentally type

```
if ('.' = ch)
```

You'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Yeah, I remember the technique... Somehow I couldn't bring myself to using it, because it reads so unnaturally. I'm so glad the modern IDEs detect missing `=` signs in conditions!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yea, I don't use it either for the same reason, I just recommend it to people as an option

Comment: @Pubby: Probably because `ch` is `const`.

Comment: @Pubby @Xeo `==` has higher precedence than `||`, but `=` has lower precedence. Therefore it was being parsed as `('(' || ch) = ')'`

Comment: This common mistake has shown up at least a couple of times today on SO alone!

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you are using `=` (assignment) rather the `==` (equality):

```
if(ch=='.' || ch=='"' || ch=='(' || ch=')' || ...
                                   ___^____
                                   see here
```

What's happening is to do with the relative precedence of the various bits. Although `==` will bind at a higher level than `||`, `a == b || c == d` evaluates as `(a == b) || (c == d)`.

However, `=` does not bind at a higher level so `a == b || c = d` evaluates as `((a == b) || c) = d)`. With your code, that ends up with a part expression of:

```
('(' || ch) = ')'
```

In other words, you're trying to assign `')'` to the non-lvalue `'(' || ch`.

You actually got lucky there by not parenthesising every term (which many people do) since that would make it *syntactically* correct but not do what you expect at runtime:

```
if ((ch == '.') || (ch == '"') || (ch == '(') || (ch = ')') || ...
                                        _________^^^^^^^^^^_________
                                        will assign rather than test
```

The usual approach to avoid that is to put the constant first but, like you, I believe that's just plain *ugly:*

```
if (('.' == ch) || ('"' == ch) || ('(' == ch) || (')' = ch) || ...
                                                  ^^^^^^^^
                                                  / urk! \
```

When I'm doing that sort of thing, I tend to rely on the standard library so that my code looks better and has much less chance of being incorrect:

```
if (strchr (".\"()!,?;", ch) != NULL) {
    // It's valid.
}
```

or even better:

```
#define VALID_PUNCTUATION ".\"()!,?;"
if (strchr (VALID_PUNCTUATION, ch) != NULL) {
    // It's valid.
}
```

or even better than that, put the whole segment in a function and just use something like:

```
if (isValidPunctuation (ch)) {
    // It's valid.
}
```

(you'll still have to make sure the code in the *function* is correct but your *mainline* code will be much cleaner).