# error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token when using for loops

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [lvalue required as left operand of assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162438/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment)
>   [lvalue required as left operand of assignment (C program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570020/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-c-program)

I am getting this error  on my code and I am not sure why. Please help!
The error is:

error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token

This is the part of my code i'm having the issue with.
a and b were already previously declared as ints.

```
   int i = 0;
   for( i == a; i < = b; i = i + 1)  // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
   {  int j = 1;
      int N = static_cast<int>(sqrt(i));

      for( j = 1; j < = N; j = j + 1)   // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
      {  int P = i%j;
         if( P == 0 && j!= 1 && j!= i)
         {  j = N + 1;
         }
         if( P != 0 && j == N)
         {  cout << i << "is prime" << endl;
         }                                         
      }
   }
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `if( (P != 0 && j) = sqrt(i))`.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate.  That said, it shows poor research effort and I'm not sure why it's getting upvotes.

Comment: This question is not quite exactly the same but has exactly the same answer.  [lvalue required as left operand of assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162438/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment)

Comment: This one is a much closer match: [lvalue required as left operand of assignment (C program)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570020/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-c-program)

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to do

```
if( P != 0 && j == sqrt(i))
```

`=` is the **assignment** operator, `==` tests for **equivalence** and returns boolean.

The assignment operator has lesser [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than logical AND (`&&`), so it being read as

```
(P != 0 && j) = sqrt(i)
```

which is why the lvalue error is being reported.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the low precedence of assignment, what you wrote:

```
if (P != 0 && j = sqrt(i))
```

is interpreted as:

```
if ((P != 0 && j) = sqrt(i))
```

and you can see that is not an l-value.  If you want to assign the square root of `i` to `j`, you probably should write:

```
if (P != 0 && (j = sqrt(i)) != 0.0)
```

assuming that `j` is a floating point variable; if it's an integer type, use `0` in place of `0.0`.  Otherwise, you should write:

```
if (P != 0 && j == sqrt(i))
```

which does an explicit equality comparison.

Comment: `==` has precedence over `&&`.

Comment: @Cthulhu:  You were right but worse than that, there was a missing close parenthesis.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put spaces in the <= operator :

```
i < = b;
```

becomes

```
i <= b;
```

Comment: It does matter on g++ ... I just tried

Answer (score 2):

I'll play along. The 'error' is the same in both case:

```
for( i == a; i < = b; i = i + 1)  // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
...
for( j = 1; j < = N; j = j + 1)   // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
```

The error is the '< =' which is not an operator and not valid C or C++. Sidenote, the 'i == a' in the first loop is a no-op.

Comment: I mean it has no side-effects, or to put it simply: it does nothing. It compares i to a. If they're the same, it returns 'true', otherwise it returns 'false'. But the return value is discarded and not used.

Comment: To initialize i in the for loop as the value of a, I should use "=" instead of "=="?

Comment: Correct. '==' is a check for equality. '=' is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Write the condition as follows.

```
if( (P != 0) && (j == sqrt(i)) )
```

instead of

```
if( P != 0 && j = sqrt(i))
```

This `=` sign is assignment operator, not a comparison operator. 
You need to check `if`, the left hand side is equal to the right hand side.